# When does a CloudQueueClient updates?

Tags: c#, azure

I have a WCF on a Web Role and then a Worker Role to process the messages added to an azure queue by the WCF.

I am doing the following :

```
var queue = queueStorage.GetQueueReference("myqueue");

var message = new CloudQueueMessage(string.Format("{0},{1}", pWord,processed));
queue.AddMessage(message);
```

Then I want to wait until the message has been processed, but I dont know if my queue object will get updated on its own or I have to do something about it.

On my worker role I have the following :

This is my onStart method :

```
CloudQueueClient queueClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudQueueClient();
        inputQueue = queueClient.GetQueueReference("myqueue");
```

And then on my Run method :

```
while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    // Retrieve and process a new message from the queue.
                    msg = inputQueue.GetMessage();
                    if (msg != null)
                    {
                        result = processMessage(msg);
```

On my processMessage method :

```
var messageParts = msg.AsString.Split(new char[] { ',' });
            var word = messageParts[0];
            var processed = Convert.ToBoolean(messageParts[2]);
            word = "recibido";
            processed = true;
            addMessageToQueue2(userId,processed);
            return 1;
```

Add message to queue is :

```
var queue = outputQueue.GetQueueReference("myQueue");
            var message = new CloudQueueMessage(string.Format("{0},{1}", pWord, pProcessed));
            queue.AddMessage(message);
```

Im fairly new to queues but I think this should work so all I need is just waiting until the message has been processed but dont know how it internally works.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you mean by *waiting until the message has been processed*. With Azure queues, the operation is very simple:

- Place messages on queue (with message TTL)
- Read message(s) from queue (with processing-timeout). This processing timeout says "I promise to finish dealing with this message, and then *deleting* this message, before this timeout is hit.
- The queue message *stays in the queue* but becomes invisible to all other readers during the timeout period.
- The message-reader then *deletes* the message from the queue.
- Assuming the code that *read* the queue message deletes the message before the promised timeout expires, all is good in QueueLand. **However**: If the processing goes beyond the timeout period, then the message becomes visible again. And... if someone else then reads that message, the original reader loses rights to delete it (they'll get an exception when making an attempt).

So: Long story short: You can process a message for as long as you want, within the stated timeout period, and then delete it. If your code crashes during processing, the message will eventually reappear for someone else to read. If you want to deal with *poison messages,* just look at the `DequeueCount` property of the message to see how many times it's been read (and if over a certain threshold, do something special with the message, like tuck it away in a blob or table row for future inspection by the development team).

See [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh767287.aspx) for all documented queue limits (and a detailed side-by-side comparison with Service Bus Queues).